# Integrating Factor Question in Solving Heat Equation (But not too related with heat equation)

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals, heat-equation

I was studying the first question of [this](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~peirce/m257_316_midterm2_sec102_w2014_Solutions.pdf) solution and I don't understand how the professor used integrating factor to solve for the question. My confusion occurs right at the second line of this part:

[image: confusion point]

I do not understand why he is integrating $e^{(\lambda_n^2-r)\tau}$ from $0$ to $t$.

My solution just do indefinite integral and get

$$e^{\lambda_n^2t}v_n = \frac{\sigma_ne^{(\lambda_n^2-r)t}}{\lambda_n^2-r}$$

Someone please help...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indefinite integral result should have a constant $c_n'$ at the end

$$e^{\lambda_n^2t}v_n = \frac{\sigma_ne^{(\lambda_n^2-r)t}}{\lambda_n^2-r}+c_n'$$

where $c_n'$ differs from $c_n$ by

$$c_n' - c_n =- \frac{\sigma_n}{\lambda_n^2-r}$$

The two integral results are equivalent.

Comment: Please bear with me, how did you get $c'_n - c_n$?

Comment: @soobster - You get it if compare your integral result with the one given in the question

Answer (score 1):

From the picture

$\frac{d}{dt}{e^{\lambda^2_n t v_n}}=\sigma_n e^{(\lambda^2_n-r)t}$. Now if you simply integrate LHS and RHS. we get $e^{\lambda^2_n t v_n} = \int_0^t \sigma_n e^{(\lambda^2_n-r)\tau} d\tau +C$. $\tau$ is used because limit is function of $t$. So what is the necessity of the expansion step? I guess.. In the previous lines you may have something like
$\dot{v}_n+\lambda_n^2 v_n=\sigma_n e^{-rt}$. Now if you multiply LHS and RHS by  $e^{\lambda^2_n t}$, you get the line.